# How to change font size in brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

I want to change the font size for editing in brackets from the default size to 16pt.

I go to view--> theme--> edit font size to 16pt or another size, but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View -> Theme -> Font-size: '24px'**.
If you don't write **px** at the end, it will not accept.
Good luck!

Answer (score 13):

Go to view->themes->fontsize

it works

Answer (score 12):

Try the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

### I. EDITOR FONT

1. run brackets as admin (sudo brackets or in win right click...)
2. Debug -> Open preference file -> ctrl+f "size"
3. Save both files -> go to view--> theme and there is changed font size

### II. brackets UI (menu fonts) too Small on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

See https://github.com/1beb/ui-too-small - it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Brackets>view >then select increase or decrease font size from dropdown menu. Continue until you get the size font you want. To see your changes go to Brackets>view>themes

Answer (score 1):

Like previously mentioned, you can achieve this with the [ui-too-small](https://github.com/1beb/ui-too-small) plugin.

Personally I don't like the default settings of this plugin either but you can change the setting by editing the main.js file which you can find by navigating to:

```
Help > Show Extensions Folder > Navigate to user > Navigate to ui too small > open main.js
```

I personally like the following settings (Material Design):

```
    define(function (require, exports, module) {
        "use strict";

        var ExtensionUtils = brackets.getModule("utils/ExtensionUtils");

    ExtensionUtils.addEmbeddedStyleSheet("#sidebar *, #main-toolbar *, #titlebar *, #problems-panel *,"+
    "#find-in-files-results *, #e4b-main-panel *, #status-bar *,"+
    "#main-toolbar *, #context-menu-bar *, #codehint-menu-bar *,"+
    "#quick-view-container *, #function-hint-container *  { font-size: 16px !important;"+
    " line-height: 30px !important; }"+
    ".sidebar li { min-height: 30px !important;}"+
    ".sidebar-selection, .filetree-selection { min-height: 30px !important; margin-top: 5px;}"+
    ""+".jstree-icon{margin-top:10px !important} .filetree-selection-extension{margin-top: 5px; height: 30px !important;} .jstree-rename-input{ margin-top: 2px !important; height: 30px !important;   padding-bottom: 0px !important;} "
    );
    });
```